# Route Resolver not firing observable without subscribe

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, observable, angular5

I have a route which needs some data from my Firebase db before the route is loaded.  It feels like the Route is not calling subscribe so the request is never being fired off.  Am I missing a step?

(Angular 5)

My router:

```
{
  path: 'class/:idName',
  component: ClassComponent,
  resolve: {
    classData: ClassResolver
  }
},
```

My Resolver:

```
@Injectable()
export class ClassResolver implements Resolve<any> {

    constructor(
        private db: AngularFireDatabase
    ) {}

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any {
        // return 'some data'; //This worked fine
        return this.db
           .list('/')
           .valueChanges() // Returns Observable, I confirmed this. 
           //.subscribe(); // This returns a Subscriber object if I call it and I never get any data
    }

    // I tried this and it didnt work either
    //const list = this.db
    //        .list('/')
    //        .valueChanges();
    //console.log('list', list);  // Is a Observable
    //list.subscribe(data => {
    //    console.log('data', data); // returned data
    //    return data;
    //});
    //return list; // never gets to the component
}
```

My Component:

```
public idName: string;
// Other vars

constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private db: AngularFireDatabase
) {
    // Form stuff    
}

ngOnInit() {
    // Never makes it here
    this.idName = this.route.snapshot.params.idName;
    const myclass = this.route.snapshot.data.classData;
    console.log('myclass', myclass);
}
```

I never makes it to the component.  It waits for the component to load, which it never does.  If I add the subscribe and console.out the data it returns quite quickly with the correct data, so its not the service.

---

After calling `.subscribe()` in my Resolver that now returns a `Subscriber` object.  Because my return signature allows for `any` its returning this `Subscriber` as if it was the data. This seems obvious now.

My question now becomes why isn't it resolving my `Observable`?

Comment: Yeah, you shouldn't be subscribing to the observable there. Try chaining a `do` method there and log the data passed to the function to the console to see what is being emitted on the observable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `resolve` function is returning an Observable that **never completes**.  The Observable is indeed firing (and this can be verified by adding a `tap` to its pipeline with some console-logging)—but the resolve phase won't end (and therefore your component won't load) until the Observable **completes**.  (The docs are not great at highlighting this.)

Obviously you don't want your Observable to complete either, because then you wouldn't get further data updates.

The simplest “fix” is to wrap your Observable in a **Promise**:

```js
async resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Promise<Observable<any>> {
  return this.db.list('/').valueChanges();
}
```

but this won't guarantee that Firebase has emitted its initial response, which I feel is what you're trying to ensure before the route loads.

The only approach I can see that would:

1. ensure that the component doesn't load until Firebase has returned data at least once; and
2. prevent two different Firebase reads (one by the resolver and then one by the component) for one effective operation

is to wrap your Firebase Observable in a **service**:

```js
import { Injectable, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { shareReplay } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DataService implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  constructor(private readonly db: AngularFireDatabase) {}

  /**
   * Observable to the data.
   * shareReplay so that multiple listeners don't trigger multiple reads.
   */
  public readonly data$ = this.db
    .list('/')
    .valueChanges()
    .pipe(shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: true }));

  /**
   * To trigger the first read as soon as the service is initialised,
   * and to keep the subscription active for the life of the service
   * (so that as components come and go, multiple reads aren't triggered).
   */
  private subscription?: Subscription;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = this.data$.subscribe();
  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription?.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

and then your resolver would look like this:

```js
async resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Promise<Observable<any>> {
  // ensure at least one emission has occurred
  await this.dataService.data$.pipe(take(1)).toPromise();

  // ...then permit the route to load
  return this.dataService.data$;
}
```

By wrapping your Firebase Observable in a service, you get `OnInit` and `OnDestroy` lifecycle hooks, which you can use to ensure that the observable "lives on" between component loads (and prevent multiple Firebase reads where one would suffice).  Because the data is then hanging around, subsequent loads of the data would also be quicker.  Lastly, this still enables you to use a resolver to ensure that the data will be instantly available before proceeding to load the component.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks to be correct. Have you been passing a parameter to your class route? It wont resolve without a parameter, that might be why you are not reaching your ngOnInit function. I would suggest console logging your route snapshots as well to make sure you are grabbing the right objects. I'll also post a resolve example that I got working:

**Component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  public data: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private router: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data = this.router.snapshot.data.test;
  }
}
```

**Routing.ts**

```
{ path: 'home/:id', component: HomeComponent, resolve: { test: ResolverService } },
```

**ResolverService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

@Injectable()
export class ResolverService implements Resolve<Observable<any>> {

  constructor() { }

  public resolve(route: ActivateRouteSnapShot): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.of({test: 'Test Observable'});
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
{{this.data.test}}
```

Comment: I am passing a route parameter when the `resolve` function returns a string it works fine.

I test the line from your `resolve` function, `return Observable.of({test: 'Test Observable'});` and that worked as well

Comment: Must be something to do with the Observable that Firebase function returns?

Comment: Thanks for your help, your comments helped push me in the right direction.  I was able to find a work around.  I updated the question

Comment: Glad it was helpful! ^.^

Comment: The key difference here is that the Observable is **completing**.  Resolvers, if outputting an Observable, will not resolve until that Observable completes.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a `take(1)` operator to the Observable the resolver returns so that it completes.

```
    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<any> {
        return this.db.list('/').valueChanges()
            .pipe(take(1)); // <-- The Magic
    }
```

@AlexPeters was on the right track, but you don't have to go so far as to return a promise. Just force the completion with `take(1)`. Alex is also spot-on that the docs are not very clear on this. I just spent an couple hours debugging this same issue.

Comment: I suggested a Promise-wrapped Observable so that the Observable would continue to emit subsequent updates after the route loaded.  If subsequent updates aren't needed, then a completed Observable as above would be enough.